# Why does Chrome webrtc not support iLBC audio codec now

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I tried to implement iLBC as my webrtc audio codec in latest version of Chrome, but it looks Chrome does not support iLBC now.

I also tested by create offer sample https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/create-offer/. No audio code for iLBC.

I have checked source code of webrtc in chrome, it seems iLBC is enabled, https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/master/webrtc.gni#68.

Does someone know why and how to enable Chrome support iLBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iLBC is old and WebRTC only mandates the opus and G.711 codecs for audio. While nothing forbids browsers from including additional codecs (such as ISAC), nobody cared enough about iLBC in the past for it to be included.

It is explicitly disabled in Chrome by setting rtc_include_ilbc to false here: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:.gn;l=47?q=rtc_include_ilbc